# How do you solve this recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

```
T(n) = n + T(3n/4) + 2T(n/8)
```

How do we solve this recurrence? When I use the substitution method I get the runtime to be O(n), but the answer is O(nlogn). Why? How can we use the substitution method here?

Comment: This might be helpful: [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Comment: How can you use Master's Theorem to solve the problem when you have 2 T terms @AnindyaDutta

Comment: The Master theorem generalizes to the [Akra-Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), which can be applied to this problem.  The problem with substitution is that it only works if you already know the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about math/computer science and not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

We make a guess for the solution and then we use mathematical induction to prove the the guess is correct or incorrect. We guess the solution as `T(n) = O(nLogn)`. Now we use induction
to prove our guess.

We need to prove that `T(n) <= cnLogn`. We can assume that it is true
for values smaller than `n`.

```
T(n) = n + T(3n/4) + 2T(n/8)
    <= n + cn(3/4)log(3n/4) + 2cn/8 log(n/8)
    <= n + cnlogn  + cnlog3- cnlog4 + cnlogn - cnlog8
    <= n + cnlogn + cnlogn + c
    <= cnlogn
```

Hence

```
T(n) = O(n logn)
```

Comment: Why do you drop the +n and the +c? Is it because cnlogn is the most dominating term?

Comment: Yes, because we need to consider the term which is the most dominating.

Comment: I think you need to keep the (3/4) and (1/8) longer.  `cnlogn + cnlogn = 2cnlogn`.

Comment: I don't think it matters because it gets dropped

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, I actually generalized `c`. For example, `2cnlogn` is actually 'c1nlogn` where `c1=2c` but I used the common notation `c` for all constants. Similar for `3/4c` and `1/8c`

Comment: I'm not sure about your proof, but using induction to prove Big-O complexity is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: You can use a generalized `c`, or you can use a guess-and-check method to prove an answer, but you can't do both at once (or else you could prove `T(n)=2T(n/2)` is `O(√n)`, for example).  Your proof is correct, once you keep the factors two steps longer (try writing everything explicitly if you still feel otherwise).

Comment: @user1990169 Weak induction (`T(n)` in terms of `T(n-1)`) doesn't usually work out, but strong induction (`T(n)` in terms of smaller `n`) is quite doable.  Once you know what answer you're trying to prove.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote up an answer.  Basically, if you are allowed to change the constants midway through, you can get OP's proof that `T=O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an (incorrect) proof that `T=O(n)` by showing that `T(n)≤cn`:

```
T(n) = n + T(3n/4) + 2T(n/8)
     ≤ n + c3n/4   + 2cn/8
     = n + cn
     = (c+1)n
     = c2n
```

The problem is at the end: although we can safely ignore constants because this is a big O estimate, we can’t do that when showing an upper bound.  To give a more explicit example, let’s suppose we had the recurrence: `S(n) = 1 + 64 S(n/2)` and show that `S=O(1)` by showing `S(n)≤c`:

```
S(n) = 1 + 64 S(n/2)
     ≤ 1 + 64 c
     = c2
```

On the other hand, the Master theorem tells us that `S=Θ(n^6)`.  (Basically, changing constants in the proof means that you don’t care at all about the constants (3/4, 2, 1/8, 64, 1/2) in the recurrence, and only about the inhomogeneous term (`n+` and `1+`).)

Here’s a correct proof that `T=O(n log n)` by showing that `T(n)≤cnlog n`:

```
T(n) = n + T(3n/4) + 2T(n/8)
     ≤ n + c(3n/4)log(3n/4) + 2c(n/8)log(n/8)
     = n + 3cn/4 log n + 3cn/4 log(3/4) + 2cn/8 log n + 2cn/8 log(1/8)
     = n + cn log n - 3cn/4 log(4/3) - cn/4 log(8)
     = cn log n + n [ 1 - 3c/4 log(4/3) - c/4 log(8) ]
     ≤ cn log n
```

as long as `1 ≤ c[3/4 log(4/3) + 1/4 log(8)]`, that is, `c≥1/[3/4 log(4/3)+1/4 log(8)]` (the exact value of this depends on the base of the logarithm).  The moral is that we are free to make `c` as large as we want at the beginning of the proof, but we can’t change it in the middle.

Unfortunately, this still leaves us with the problem of figuring out that we should guess `T=O(n log n)` in the first place.  If we don’t mind the overkill, we can use the [Akra–Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).  Because `1(3/4)^p+2(1/8)^p=1` when `p=1`, `T=Θ(x(1+∫ x/x² dx))=Θ(x(1+log x))=Θ(x log x)`.